# XML Deserialization Array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization

I have a class. I want to deserialize XML file into this class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string xmlFile;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xmlFile = "Sample.xml";
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Application
    {
        public string AppName;
        public string UpdateDetail;
    };

    [Serializable]
    public class Applications
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Application[] Application;
    };



    [Serializable]
    public class Pmsp_Update
    {
        public string OldVersion;
        public string NewVersion;
        public Applications Applications;
    };

    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pmsp_Update));
        Pmsp_Update pu;
        using (reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
        {
            pu = (Pmsp_Update)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<Pmsp_Update>
  <OldVersion>v4.0.0</OldVersion>
  <NewVersion>v4.0.1</NewVersion>
  <Applications>
    <Application>
      <AppName>SampleApp</AppName>
      <UpdateDetail>sample</UpdateDetail>
     </Application>
  </Applications>
</Pmsp_Update>
```

I want to ask about attributes. I only used `[Serializable]` attribute and I can get the class. I don't use any `[XmlElement]` attribute and this didn't cause any error except one.

If I use like this I can populate the array but:

```
        [Serializable]
        public class Applications
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public Application[] Application;
        };
```

If I use like this I can't populate the array:

```
[Serializable]
public class Applications
{
    public Application[] Application;
};
```

So, my question is this: I am not using `[XmlElement]` for fields and everything works well but I can't populate the array. Why couldn't I populate the array when I don't use `[XmlElement]` although I can populate the fields?

Comment: `[Serializable]` has nothing to do with `XmlSerializer`. It enables binary serialization.

Comment: If I dont use [Serializable] how can I enable class to be serialized. And my question is not about [Serializable]. But what, thanks

Comment: There's no *enable* for XML serialization. It *just works*. The various *[Xml...]* attributes are here to further control the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check what's going on is to create object of your class and serialize it to XML. This is what I get:

***Without `[XmlElement]`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Pmsp_Update xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OldVersion>v4.0.0</OldVersion>
  <NewVersion>v.4.0.1</NewVersion>
  <Applications>
    <Application>
      <Application>
        <AppName>Test</AppName>
        <UpdateDetail>test</UpdateDetail>
      </Application>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Pmsp_Update>
```

***With `[XmlElement]`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Pmsp_Update xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OldVersion>v4.0.0</OldVersion>
  <NewVersion>v.4.0.1</NewVersion>
  <Applications>
    <Application>
      <AppName>Test</AppName>
      <UpdateDetail>test</UpdateDetail>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Pmsp_Update>
```

As you can see, only the second one matches your input XML, and that's why you cannot deserialize yout XML without `[XmlElement]` attribute - **because your XML document does not match your class structure**.

Empty `XmlElement` on top of array property prevent serializer from expecting additional element to handle array elements. That behavior is described on MSDN: [`XmlElementAttribute Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If you apply the `XmlElementAttribute` to a field or property that
>   returns an array, the items in the array are encoded as a sequence of
>   XML elements.
>
> In contrast if an `XmlElementAttribute` is not applied to
>   such a field or property, the items in the array are encoded as a
>   sequence of elements, nested under an element named after the field or
>   property. (Use the `XmlArrayAttribute` and `XmlArrayItemAttribute`
>   attributes to control how an array is serialized.)

You can achieve the same by changing your class structure to

```
public class Application
{
    public string AppName;
    public string UpdateDetail;
};

public class Pmsp_Update
{
    public string OldVersion;
    public string NewVersion;
    public Application[] Applications;
};
```

`<Applications>` element will be added automatically for array property, so you don't need `Applications` class.